# Duda con metodo Replace

Tags: python

Tengo un DataFrame Time

```
0      2020-01-06 08:00:00
1      2020-01-06 09:00:00
2      2020-01-06 10:00:00
3      2020-01-06 11:00:00
4      2020-01-06 12:00:00
```

Necesito reemplazar `2020-01-06` por `2020-06-01`

Intenté hacer `df.Time=df.Time.replace("2020-01-06","2020-06-01")`

Pero no está funcionado, en que estoy errando?

Comment: Te da algún error? O el Dataframe está sin cambios luego del comando?

Comment: No da ningún error, solo no da ningún cambio. Estaba testando si coloco `df.Time=df.Time.replace("2020-01-06 08:00:00","2020-06-01 08:00:00")` si funciona pero para la primera fila. Yo necesito que identifique todos los `2020-01-06` sin los horarios

Comment: Quizá en el dataframe estás poniendo la fecha y la hora en la misma columna. Es decir, cuando creas el dataframe, haces data=((1,2...), ("2020-01-06 08:00:00","2020-01-06 09:00:00")). Estoy en lo correcto? Si no es el caso, podrías agregar el código con el cual generas el dataframe por favor?

Comment: Por que tengo la sospecha de que la fecha y la hora están en la misma columna sin que te des cuenta.

Comment: De hecho si, la fecha y la hora están en la misma columna, en realidad es una condición de mis datos, deben estar así. La lógica es que básicamente tengo `df="a b"` y debo reemplazar por `"a2 b"` donde `a` es la fecha y `b` la hora. Si bien, aún no entiendo si es realmente posible hacer ese reemplazo

Comment: Me da miedo darte una respuesta fuera de la sección de comentarios ya que no tengo ni idea de como funciona. Por ahora algo que podrías usar es esto: `df[1] = df[1].str.replace("2020-01-06", "2020-06-01")`. Te recomiendo estar al pendiente de tu pregunta por si aparece una respuesta que sea mejor que mi comentario. Pues yo se muy poco del modulo Pandas. Pero espero que mi comentario te sirva para continuar mientras tanto.

Comment: Recien me doy cuenta que hice un copy-paste sin pensar de mi código de prueba. Me explico. Hice pruebas con un dataframe propio cuya segunda columna es 1. Puedes cambiar df[1] por df.Time

Comment: El problema es que pandas infiere el tipo de dato así que estarías aplicando el replace a una columna de tipo datetime y no str, puedes convertir la columna y luego con el replace funcionará

Comment: Me parece que tienes en primer lugar un problema en la interpretación de fechas, es decir, tienes un dato que pareciera estar como año-día-mes y lo quieres pasar a año-mes-dia, puedes ciertamente hacer un replace, pero si tienes una fecha que sea  2020-02-06 ya no te va a alcanzar ese replace.